# Send funds with Fees Included or Not Included?

Tags: purchasing, payments, fees

Is it possible, to program in an option for sending funds minus fees, or  plus fees? To have a choice, depending on the situation.

For example, I want to use Lumens to pay for coffee, it's $5.00.

I want to pay for the coffee, and cover the fee, so I send $5.00001, merchant receives exactly $5.00.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to send lumens directly on the Stellar Network without the sender paying the fee. This fee is built directly into the Stellar Network.

"[Stellar deducts the entire fee from the transaction’s source account, regardless of which accounts are involved in each operation or who signed the transaction.](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#transaction-fee)"

Comment: I don't have a problem with sender paying the fee, but I would like to see an option with future payment tools, where you can transfer funds and have a default setting where sender covers the fee amount, and the receiver gets the full amount intended.This question stems from a post where the objection to Stellar Lumens service, is if I'm paying for $5 for an item, the receiving party gets $5, minus the fee.It would just be cleaner, to cover fee as a sender.

Comment: I see, in that case the simplest solution would be to integrate the fee into a wallet application. I suspect if no wallets currently have feature they will in the future. A UI for this would say something like "Wallet Receives" where you simply put in the amount you want the receiver to get in their wallet and the fee is added, kind of like tax on a restaurant bill.

Answer (score 3):

Fees are always paid for in the native currency (XLM), so you can't cover the cost of a transaction using USD like in your example

Answer (score 1):

If you send $5.00, the receiver (destination) will receive $5.00, always.
The fee of XLM 0.00001 will be deducted from your account (source account)

Comment: I believe this is the answer the OP was looking for. The network already performs how they would like it to.

Answer (score 0):

Adding fee is not possible, at least you not force the source account holder to sign another operation that pays you the fee

Refunding the fee is possible in various way:

- If you are the one who post transaction to horizon, you can easily parse the xdr and extract the source account to refund
- You can monitor the source/destination account for new transaction and trigger your fee refund policy

In both case you should keep in mind that "refund transaction" has fee too